# How can I expose the "Content-Disposition" in spring-integration (DSL)?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

For downloading a file I will add the "Content-Disposition" to my responseHeader but it doesn't work.

The response will not have any added properties.

```
    @Bean
    public ExpressionParser fileParser() {
        return new SpelExpressionParser();
    }

    @Bean
    public HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> fileHeaderMapper() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
    }
```

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpGetFileDownload() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Http.inboundGateway("/api/files/download/{id}")
                        .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(HttpMethod.GET))
                        .statusCodeExpression(fileParser().parseExpression("T(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus).BAD_REQUEST"))
                        .payloadExpression(fileParser().parseExpression("#pathVariables.id"))
                        .crossOrigin(cors -> cors.origin("*").exposedHeaders("Content-Disposition", "content-disposition"))
                        .headerMapper(fileHeaderMapper())
                )
                .channel("http.file.download.channel")
                .handle("fileEndpoint", "download")
                .get();
    }



public Message<?> download(Message<Long> msg){
...

return MessageBuilder
                    .withPayload(resource)
                    .copyHeaders(msg.getHeaders())
                    .setHeader(STATUSCODE_HEADER, HttpStatus.OK)
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType)
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, (int)file.length())
                    .build();
}
```

What I get:

cache-control: "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate" 
content-type: "application/json"
expires: "0"
pragma: "no-cache"

Comment: HI Ryan did you try to use the ContentDisposition.builder()?

Comment: No. Where should I bind this method? In my handler?

Comment: to create your HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: What is your `fileHeaderMapper`? The `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` maps a `HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION` into HTTP response. So, we need to know what that your one does. On the other hand it  would be great if you have some simple project to share with us for debugging.

Comment: I added my Expressionparser and HeaderMapper

Comment: I checked my returning Message. The Content-Disposition is set in the header, but doesn't receive by my frontend.

Comment: How does it work if you really use a `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper()` instead? See it’s JavaDocs for more info

Comment: That's work fine. But what is the difference now between using a Bean and using the `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper()`

Comment: You didn’t get it: the factory method adds specific headers to map. A default constructor - doesn’t. I’ll add a more comprehensive answer later today or tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` is empty by default. I think it might be a time to make the ctor as `deprecated` to not allow to use it from end application.
Or to make some validation to reject just empty (not configured) `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper`...

It is also confusing what is the point to use that `return new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();` if your don't customize it. There is a default one in the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway`:

```
private HeaderMapper<HttpHeaders> headerMapper = DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper();
```

To fix your problem you definitely need to use this `inboundMapper()` factory method, which does this:

```
/**
 * Factory method for creating a basic inbound mapper instance.
 * This will map all standard HTTP request headers when receiving an HTTP request,
 * and it will map all standard HTTP response headers when sending an HTTP response.
 * @return The default inbound mapper.
 */
public static DefaultHttpHeaderMapper inboundMapper() {
    DefaultHttpHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultHttpHeaderMapper();
    setupDefaultInboundMapper(mapper);
    return mapper;
}
```

That `setupDefaultInboundMapper()` is very important: it brings for us a set of headers to map from the request and into response.